# Executing a function from Database Result

Tags: php

I'm working on calling scripts from the database if they match a function that's included.
Right here is what I'm using now:
3 Functions to Call Page Content:

```
    public function ViewPageDetails() {
        global $db;
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT title,body
        FROM inv_pages
        WHERE id = :getid
SQL;
        $resource = $db->db->prepare( $query );
        $resource->execute( array (
        ':getid'    => $_GET['id'],
        ));
        foreach($resource as $row){
            $this->title = $row['title'];
            $this->body = $row['body'];
        }
    }
    public function ViewPageTitle() {
        self::ViewPageDetails();
        return $this->title;
    }
    public function ViewPageBody() {
        self::ViewPageDetails();
            if( is_callable($this->body) )
                        $this->body();
                    else {
                        echo $this->body;
                    }
    }
```

I thought that that would work to call the function, but instead throws the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method pages::body()
```

Now a function I do have that would work on the flip side is

```
public function testcall() {
        global $db;
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT body
        FROM inv_pages
        WHERE id = :getid
SQL;
        $resource = $db->db->prepare( $query );
        $resource->execute( array (
        ':getid'    => $_GET['id'],
        ));
        foreach($resource as $row){
        if( is_callable($row['body']) )
                        $row['body']();
                    else {
                        echo $row['body'];
                    }
        }
    }
```

So `$this->body()` is an illegal method, but `$row['body']()` is perfectly fine to call. If anyone knows a way to use `$this->body()` instead of `$row['body']()` any input would be appreciated. If you need clarification please ask. I think I put the issue in pretty well however.